# Schedule Cronjob change runtime - JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to pass value run time and according to value I need to change the cronjob executing intervals but when I use @Scheduled() and I can't do it since it required constant. How can I do it or if there is any alternative way ? I also can't assign env.getProperty value to variable outside the local method.

```
  String cronValue=env.getProperty("cron");


    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *", zone = "Asia/Colombo")
    public void createFile() throws IOException {

        String location=env.getProperty("location");

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Colombo" ) );
        String date = today.toString();
        String source=location+"report-temp.csv";
        String dailyFile=location+"report-"+date+".csv";



        // File (or directory) with old name
        File oldFile = new File("/home/lkr/nish/report-temp.csv");


        File newFile = new File(dailyFile);
        //if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");


        boolean success = oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
        if (!success) {
            // File was not successfully renamed
        }


        System.out.println("Daily File Created!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you might try to use [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) Spring interface.

Basically, it allows you to call a schedule method and pass a [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) params.

In that case your calls needs to implement Runnable and to parametrize your dynamical periods of execution in a Date format. Lets say that you have a class named FileGenerator and that it implements Runnable. It will also have to implement methods of Runnable interfance, hence you will have to have method called run();

```
class FileGenerator implements Runnable {
    TaskScheduler scheduler;
    Date parametrizedDate;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        scheduler.schedule(this::createFile, parametrizedDate);
    }


    private void createFile() {

        String location=env.getProperty("location");

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Colombo" ) );
        String date = today.toString();
        String source=location+"report-temp.csv";
        String dailyFile=location+"report-"+date+".csv";

        // File (or directory) with old name
        File oldFile = new File("/home/lkr/nish/report-temp.csv");

        File newFile = new File(dailyFile);
        //if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

        boolean success = oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
        if (!success) {
            // File was not successfully renamed
        }

        System.out.println("Daily File Created!");
    }
```

Since TaskScheduler is an interface itself, you'll have to configure one of its implementations, preferably within a bean. One possibility to do that with a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:

```
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
```

All that is left to do is to autowire the bean with the field and to provide the Date you want to pass.

EDIT:
This interface also provides you with methods to which you can pass a timespan (fixed or with a delay). A bit more about it [here](https://thebackendguy.com/spring-schedule-tasks-or-cron-jobs-dynamically/)